# URL Encode and Google %3F and %3D

Tags: apache, url, uri

Anyone can help to solve this.

I got message in Adsense that google get "Page Not Found" for more than 10K pages :) (yes it is a big site).

Problematic urls have at and %3F and %3D. How to fix that coz this is problem for large number of my urls...and all they look at end:

http://mysite.com/some-perma-links?full=1

ps. I know that is problem ? and = but how to fix that on Apache or on .htaccess for all urls?

I have dedicated server so I can fix on Apache or on htaccess

Comment: How is Google getting to the pages with %3F/%3D at the end? through actual site links, auto-generated sitemap or other file?

Comment: What does `full=1` actually do in the URLs?

Comment: This: ?full=1 at end of url is parameter and tell wordpress "if is in url full=1 then show page with full size image". Here is one of pages where is that url with parameter (when you click on zoom icon) http://fabzz.com/emma-watson-leggy-candids-in-new-york-city.html/emma-watson-leggy-05

Comment: Also if I copy ie this url: http://fabzz.com/emma-watson-leggy-candids-in-new-york-city.html/emma-watson-leggy-05?full=1   and paste that in Google Webmaster Tools under: Fetch as Google ... google return 404 page coz he "auto" convert links with ? and = in encoded urls...it is strange that he won't pick urls like he found on web page